# Dropping rational coefficients

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pattern-matching, symbolic, expression-manipulation

I have a list of expressions (they all are exact numeric quantities, not containing any variables), some of them have integer or rationals coefficients, or complex coefficients with rational or integer components. There are no sums of several terms. I am looking for a simple and elegant way to drop those coefficients from all expressions in the list. This is what I wrote so far

```
ClearAll[normalize];
normalize[0] = 0;
normalize[_?ExactNumberQ] = 1;
normalize[z_Times] := DeleteCases[z, _?ExactNumberQ];
normalize[z_] := z;

normalize /@ {484/45, -16 EulerGamma/3, -8 Log[2], (48/5 + 2 I/5) Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}
(* {1, EulerGamma, Log[2], Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]} *)
```

Could you suggest anything better?

Comment: `Replace[x, r_?ExactNumberQ :> 1, {0, 1}]`?

Comment: Nope, I have to check for the `Times` head, otherwise it will corrupt terms like `PolyGamma[0, 1/Sqrt[2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Replace[{484/45, -16 EulerGamma/3, -8 Log[2], 
        PolyGamma[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], (48/5 + 2 I/5) Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}, 
        _?ExactNumberQ -> 1, 2]

(* {1, EulerGamma, Log[2], PolyGamma[1, 1/Sqrt[2]], Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}*)
```

Comment: …notice that the digamma function in the fourth entry has suddenly become a trigamma function.

Comment: I didn't, thanks. Moreover, if there is a Power[2, Rational[1,2]] at first level it is replaced by 1 and I guess this is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
Replace[x_.*Except[0]?ExactNumberQ :> x]
```

concisely satisfies all of your criteria.  Consider:

```
Replace[x_.*Except[0]?ExactNumberQ :> x] /@ 
    {0, 484/45, -16 EulerGamma/3, -8 Log[2], PolyGamma[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], (48/5 + 2 I/5) Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}
```

> {0, 1, EulerGamma, Log[2], PolyGamma[0, 1/Sqrt[2]], 
>    Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could use [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList):

```
Map[
    Last @ FactorTermsList[#, _Symbol]&,
    {484/45, -16 EulerGamma/3, -8 Log[2], (48/5 + 2 I/5) Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}
]
```

> {1, EulerGamma, Log[2], Sqrt[2] Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]}